# PGP Encryption Fails on Large Files

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, pgp, encryption-asymmetric

I'm in this weird situation.
I'm trying to encrypt this 11GB which has ~42 Million rows in it using PGP with RSA/Armored Public Key.

Here are the commands I used:

Import Key -> 
`gpg --import ~/underwood/keys/my_pub_4096_RSA_key.asc`

PGP Encryption -

```
gpg -r "underwood@publickey.com" -o /usr/local/encrrypted-file/encrypted-11GB-file.txt.pgp
--armor --encrypt /usr/local/file-to-encrrypt/this-is-a-11GB-file.txt
```

`

Issue :
The file size of `/usr/local/encrrypted-file/encrypted-11GB-file.txt.pgp` is 4GB and row count is only 8M. I'm not sure what happened here. The command completed successfully after 3min without errors.

Question:

1. How do I further investigate this issue ?
2. Is there a cap on gpg command on file size ? Because this command workds perfectly fine with 500MB file.
3. How do I achieve full encryption on 11GB file ?

One solution I can think on top of my head is to chunk the 11GB in 500MB files and do this. But the problem here, I'm not allowed to chunk the file.

Please let me know if there is a better solution to this.

Comment: You indicate you are not allowed to chunk the file;  Can you clarify that requirement or put it in other words?  E.g. "I must have a single file as output" or "I must use only a single gpg command to decrypt" or ....

Answer (score 0):

See unix split function to split a binary file into pieces.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail how this might be useful, or give an example of how to use it, or maybe a man page excerpt showing your suggested flags?